# Will this variable be visible?

Tags: ansible

I have a simple playbook:

```
- name: "Ensure /etc/host contains '127.0.0.1'"
  lineinfile:
    name: /etc/host
    line: "127.0.0.1"
    state: present
  check_mode: yes
  register: conf


- name: "Use java role playbook"
  roles:
   - role: java  
     if_exist: conf
```

My question: Will this `conf` variable be visible and assigned to `if_exist`?

Answer (score 1):

First you can use shell module to read the file and register the output, then use "when" to search for a specific content in the registered output of the file and base of the result run the task.

```
 - name: cat
    shell: "cat /etc/host "
    register: conf

  - include_role: 
      name:  
    when: conf.stdout.find('127.0.0.1') != 1
```

Comment: You can use [slurp module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/slurp_module.html) instead of shell + cat

Answer (score -1):

It's possible even without `cat/grep/awk`, just use Ansible's `lookup` and `search`.

```
vars:
   out: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/host') }}"

tasks:
  - name: "Use java role playbook"
    include_role:
      name: Java
    when: out is search("127.0.0.1")
```

Comment: lookup returns the contents from a file on the Ansible controller’s file system, not the remote one ! https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/lookup/file.html#synopsis

Comment: That's true, but OP didn't specify environment. (local or remote) ::)